# how does find_package work in CONFIG mode

Tags: cmake

I use find_package in CONFIG mode to find Qt5:

```
find_package(Qt5 CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
```

I don't specify CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and `/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin` is not set in PATH but cmake finds *Config.cmake files:

```
/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
```

How does it work ? How cmake create search paths ?

**Edit1**

I read a documentation but it is unclear for me:

```
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/cmake/<name>*/          (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/                (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/  (U)
```

What is the prefix ? How the above patterns match to the Qt path ? :

```
/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
```

I have created a similar path for my library:

```
/home/user/Mylib/1.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Mylib1/Mylib1Config.cmake
```

but `find_package(Mylib1 CONFIG)` returns an error:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Mylib1" with any
of the following names:

Mylib1Config.cmake
mylib1-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Mylib1" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Mylib1_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Mylib1"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
```

Comment: There are much more prefixes, searched by CMake for find config files. See documentation on `find_package`: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html

Comment: This is an interesting question. Have you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Taken `<prefix>` as `/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64`, full directory name for `Qt5Config.cmake` can be obtained via that template:

`<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|**lib**|share)/cmake/<name>*/`

As for origin of the prefix itself, I guess it comes from [User Package Registry](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#user-package-registry):

> 6. Search paths stored in the CMake User Package Registry. This can be skipped if NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY is passed. See the cmake-packages(7) manual for details on the user package registry.

You can check content of `~/.cmake/packages/` folder for check that registry's content.

Comment: I don't have any .cmake directory. Why cmake can't find Mylib1 mentioned above ?

Comment: `Why cmake can't find Mylib1 mentioned above ?` - Because prefix `/home/user/**Mylib**/1.0/gcc_64/` is not known by CMake. You could try do the same with `/home/user/QT/5.5/1.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Mylib1/Mylib1Config.cmake`

Comment: So cmake is installed with some list of prefixes, right ?

Comment: May be. Most likely, `/home/user/QT/5.5/1.0/gcc_64` prefix comes with QT installation in some way.

Comment: The question is asking where is the `<prefix>`'s value from, however this answer doesn't answer that.

Comment: @nn0p: The answer explains question `How the above patterns match to the Qt path?` which is contained in the question post. As for origin of the prefix, the answer contains *guessing*. Probably, this guessing is wrong (as asker PC doesn't contain `~/.cmake` directory), but the answer remains an answer (from the Stack Overflow point of view). If you have another opinion (more or less confident) about origin of the `<prefix>`, you are welcome to provide another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin` is in your `PATH` for example, cmake will search the sibling lib directories automatically.